# How to write JSON array to file in node.js and request it again client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to create a drag-and-drop table with save and load functionality. I'm using code from [REDIPS.drag](https://www.redips.net/category/javascript/drag-and-drop/).

When using the REDIPS save function the table content is returned, client side, to the console and alert like this:

```
[["d2",2,2,"blue","A1"],["d1",4,5,"blue","A2"],["d3",3,2,"blue","A3"],["d4",1,4,"blue","A4"]].
```

I've tried a few different ways to POST the data to node and write it to file.

With this method:

script.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"post6/json",
    data: {table_content},
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
});
```

App.js

```
var testjson = req.body;
var tablestringify2 = JSON.stringify(testjson); 
fs.writeFile('views/test.json', tablestringify2,'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        // append failed
    } else {
        // done
    }
})
```

The data saved to file is:

```
{"table_content":"[[\"ns1.8b\",3,1,\"\",\"ns1.8b\"],[\"ns3.1\",4,2,\"\",\"ns3.1\"]]"}
```

With this method:

script.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"post6/json",
    data: table_content,
    dataType:'json',
});
```

The data is saved to file as:

```
{"[":{"\"ns1.8b\",3,0,\"\",\"ns1.8b\"":{"\"ns3.1\",3,2,\"\",\"ns3.1\"":""}}}
```

When I use a GET, I parse the data which returns;

```
{ table_content: '[["ns1.8b",3,1,"","ns1.8b"],["ns3.1",5,3,"","ns3.1"]]' }
```

or

```
{[:{"ns1.8b",3,0,"","ns1.8b":{"ns3.1",3,2,"","ns3.1":""}}}
```

Either form cant be loaded back into the table using the REDIPS load function.

Is there any way I could get the data in the following format;

```
[["ns1.8b",3,0,"","ns1.8b"],["ns3.1",3,2,"","ns3.1"]]
```

...returned on the client side?

Or would it be possible to save it to file like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the stringify at the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"post6/json",
    data: {table_content: JSON.stringify(table_content)},
    dataType:'json',
});
```

At the server side you should be able to access `req.body.table_content` which will be the (JSON) string representation of the array.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just tried it now. Thanks for your help!